# “This post is associated with an ad and may not be edited this time” message in Facebook

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-timeline, ads

Is there any way to edit a Facebook post if it is associated with an ad? The edit option is greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. When you submitted the post, the ad was approved for the content placed at that time of submittal. You will need to remove the ad and redo the process.